# Capitalisation Question Regarding Awards

Tags: capitalization

I have written this sentence and am unsure whether or not I should capitalise "math" or "science".

At my grade eight graduation I was presented with the Head Boy award, the math award, the science award, and the Principal’s Award for Student Leadership.

OR

At my grade eight graduation I was presented with the Head Boy award, the Math award, the Science award, and the Principal’s Award for Student Leadership.

Thanks

Comment: If the math, science, and head boy awards are officially designated as such, then all three should be rendered as the proper names they are (just as the Principal’s Award for Student Leadership is): Math Award, Science Award, Head Boy Award. But if they are simply descriptive names for the awards, I don't see why capitalization should enter into the picture at all: math award, science award, head boy award.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question!

If you're just talking about a math problem, "math" is not capitalized. But if you're referring to the field of mathematics in a very formal sense (a great thinker in Math)*, or the name of the class where mathematics is taught (Math III), or the school subject (Math, English, History), it's Math with a capital "M". It's the same for Science.

For that reason I would go with your second example, where all the subjects are capitalized. But wait, that's not all -- there's more!

The fact that it's a *title of an award* means you might want to capitalize **all** the nouns. This isn't just a math award or the Math award; it's the Math Award (with capital letters for formality and importance!). So it would be the **Head Boy Award**, the **Math Award**, the **Science Award**, and the **Principal's Award for Student Leadership**.

* *this sense may be a bit outdated; I'm not sure if this type of capitalization is used very often anymore; thoughts?*